# Mirroring in weight painting mode is distorted

Tags: weight-painting

I apologize if this question seems stupid, I am a total noob in Blender.
Whenever I try to mirror the weight on a bone, it comes out all splattered and distorted. I have two screenshots of what happens. [image]

[image]

Comment: just to rule stuff out, are your transforms all applied?

Comment: could you please share your file (at least the armature + arms)? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: May you tell me how I apply all transformations? Because I'm not sure if I've already done that. Thank you.

Comment: ctrl + a and apply all transforms, then try the weight painting again

Comment: I tried going to object mode to apply the transformations, but the same error happens.